# Нужна ли запятая? Может быть, не одна?

Tags: пунктуация

*Эта фраза показывает, что даже тяжелый труд во благо детей приносит удовольствие.*

Answer (score 2):

Только запятая перед "что" необходима (это запятая между главным и придаточным предложением). Нет причин для постановки других запятых. Здесь нет ни уточняющих слов, ни вводных конструкций, которые требовали бы постановки запятых.

Answer (score 2):

Единственная нужная здесь запятая - на месте (об этом уже ответили), но меня привлекло другое: не сочетается родительный падеж с устойчивым сочетанием "*во благо*". Нужно либо "**на благо детей**" (если родительный), либо "**во благо детям**" (дательный) - видимо, потому и не читается, как уже замечено. Нашлась целая статья на эту тему:

http://www.sekretarskoe-delo.ru/index.php?id=1368

(Рассмотрены особенности отклонений варианта с "на" от общего правила: *Предлог «на благо» употребляется с родительным падежом: на благо страны, на благо Отечества. С дательным падежом употребляется оборот «во благо»: во благо себе, во благо общему делу.*)

Answer (score 1):

> Эта фраза показывает, что(,) даже тяжелый труд(,) во благо детей(,)
>   приносит удовольствие.

По-моему, данное предложение лучше будет читаться со словом "если":

***Эта фраза показывает, что даже тяжелый труд, если он во благо детей, приносит удовольствие.***

Answer (score 0):

**Эта фраза показывает, что даже тяжелый труд во благо детей приносит удовольствие.**

Вроде бы всё верно в грамматике этого  предложении, **но оно не читается**.

**Что это значит?** Непонятно, какое слово во второй части должно быть интонационно выделено ("тяжЁлый труд" или "во блАго детей"). Неясно, где сделать произносительную паузу во второй части, состоящей из 8 слов,  а ее надо сделать, так как мы не можем такой речевой объем произносить на одном дыхании. И в результате создается впечатление, что **предложение надо как-то исправить, чтобы оно лучше читалось.**

Поэтому приходится сделать вывод, что сочетание "**тяжелый труд во благо детей**" не лучшим образом вписывается в данную структуру и **желательна правка**. (При этом письменный вариант предложения может смотреться нормально).

Предлагаемый вариант: **Эта фраза показывает, что труд во благо детей, даже тяжелый, всегда  приносит удовольствие.**

В этом случае **интонационно выделены** и  "тяжёлый труд", и "во благо детей".

Comment: Бог ты мой... ужас какой. Дай вам волю, вы бы половину Льва Толстого переправили... чтобы соблюсти "интонацию". И Достоевского. Уж он-то точно об "интонации" мало заботился. Всё-таки умствовать вредно... Ох и вредно.